# Generic interface as parameter java

Tags: java, methods, interface

Is it possible use generic interface as paramter of method?

```
public interface A {
  public void Trans(interface)
}
```

Comment: use `Class<?>` as type, maybe?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: No, Classes and interfaces in Java are indistinguishable in sense of arguments typing.

Comment: What's generic here?

Comment: can you tell us why you want to do this, and what you want to achieve by doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.
The way you did it will give a syntax error though.

```
public interface B
{
  ....
}

public interface A
{
  public void trans(B theInterface);
}
```

Comment: OP is talking about passing an interface as parameter. In your example you are passing an object, not an interface.

Comment: @BackSlash: You're right if OP is actually trying to do that. In that case, please consider comment posted by RC